# Combining two Runnable objects

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, green-threads

Say for example that I have a Runnable called RunnableA that does something. I also have a Runnable called RunnableB that does something else. Is there a way that I can combine these two Runnables someway so that they will run in the same thread?

The second part of the question is if this is possible, can I then specify the order that they will run in?

EDIT!: The reason why I wanted to do this was because I need to run code on the EDT but some of the other code needs to be run on another thread. Please take a look at the code below.

Something like this

```
public final class CompoundRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final Iterable runnables;

    public CompoundRunnable(Iterable runnables)
    {
        // From Guava. Easy enough to do by hand if necessary
        this.runnables = Lists.newArrayList(runnables);

    }

    public CompoundRunnable(Runnable... runnables)
    {
        this(Arrays.asList(runnables));
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (Runnable runnable : runnables)
        {
             runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public void setStatusAndProgress(final String status,Runnable runnable)
    {
        Runnable startUpRunner = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        setStatus(status);
                        selfReference.getProgressBar().setIndeterminate(true);
                    }

                });
            }
        };
        Runnable cleanUpRunner = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        setStatus("");
                        getProgressBar().setIndeterminate(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        Runnable theRunner = new CompoundRunnable(startUpRunner,runnable,cleanUpRunner);
        new Thread(theRunner).start();
    }
```

Sorry if this isnt explained well, post comments if you need clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need these run on the same thread, in a specified order, its not exactly a multithreaded problem. Can you extract your code from the runnables instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you can certainly create a `Runnable` which just runs one runnable then the other:

```
public final class CompoundRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final Runnable first;
    private final Runnable second;

    public CompoundRunnable(Runnable first, Runnable second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        first.run();
        second.run();
    }
}
```

More generally, you could make it take an `Iterable<Runnable>`, copy all the `Runnable` references, and then run them in order. For example:

```
public final class CompoundRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final Iterable<Runnable> runnables;

    public CompoundRunnable(Iterable<Runnable> runnables)
    {
        // From Guava. Easy enough to do by hand if necessary
        this.runnables = Lists.newArrayList(runnables);
    }

    public CompoundRunnable(Runnable... runnables)
    {
        this(Arrays.asList(runnables));
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (Runnable runnable : runnables)
        {
             runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have modified your code a bit and used it in the example above. Can you let me know what you think?

Comment: @user489041: Well you've removed the generics to start with... why?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I couldnt use the function Lists.newArrayList(runnables). Is this part of com.google.common.collect.Lists?

Comment: @user489041: Yes, it is. But even if you want to create a new `ArrayList` yourself and do it manually, it would still be worth using generics.

Comment: Agreed, I just added Guava to my project. I updated the code above accordingly. It actually worked pretty well. Any other comments or suggestions?

Comment: @user489041: The same one as before: *use generics*. Your updated code *still* doesn't use generics... why not?

Comment: I suppose it would be my lack of knowledge on generics. Im not sure I fully understand what that would do to the code.

Comment: @user489041: Generics are basically about type safety - making sure you don't try to put a String into a list of Integers for example. I *strongly* recommend that you read up on them.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just create another runnable that calls the run methods of your two existing Runnable's as part of its implementation. You can make the wrapping Runnable purpose-built or generic with a list of Runnables, etc.

```
public Runnable combineRunnables(Runnable a, Runnable b)
{
   Runnable retVal = new Runnable()
   {
        public void run()
        {
            a.run();
            b.run();
        } 
   };

   return retVal;
}
```

Perhaps what's confusing you is association of Runnable with threads. The Runnable interface isn't tied to threads and doesn't by itself have any threading semantics, so you can easily combine it like above without somehow getting into trouble with thread states.

Comment: Yes, I think that is why I am getting confused. I think that I am way over thinking it. I was looking for a general way that I could take some start up and shut down code on the EDT and then run some worker code in its own thread. This is why I was wondering if I could combine them in such a way. My attempt based of the responses was posted above.

Comment: Probably should catch exceptions from the first and pass it to the uncaught exception handler. It's unfortunate that `Runnable` is given so little meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can of course combine them. In general though, there shouldn't be much inside a runnable except a call to some other object, to actually get the work done. Can you not just take the "insides" of the runnables you need and execute them in the context you want.

If you want to make sure things are simply executed one after the other, rather than at the same time you can use a SingleThreadExecutorService and give them the Runnables. It will execute one at a time.

If you really want to run multiple runnables then you can do it like this (the first RuntimeException will exit).

Note the static convenience method so you can say "new Thread(CompositeRunnable.combine(a,b,c,d....))"

```
public class CompositeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final Runnable[] runnables;

    public CompositeRunnable(Runnable... runnables) {
        this.runnables = runnables;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (Runnable runnable : runnables) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }

    public static Runnable combine(Runnable... runnables) {
        return new CompositeRunnable(runnables);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation.

```
public static Runnable combineRunnables(final Runnable... runnables) {
   return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(Runnable r: runnables) r.run();
        } 
   };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody suggested the more flexible approach, which just so happens to be also the simplest and and shortest solution compared to the existing answers.

Just create a new class `RunList` that subclasses one of the concrete `List` implementations (e.g. `ArrayList`) and then declare it implements `Runnable`

```java
public class RunList extends ArrayList<Runnable> implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Runnable runner : this) {
            runner.run();
        }
    }
}
```

With that class defined, you can then go about defining:

```
RunList runList = new RunList()
```

And then populate `runList` with all of the `Runnables` you want to run. You now have the full Java language and standard library at your disposal here for reordering or general manipulation of the list.

Some example (untested) usage is included below.

```java
public void testRunList() {

    RunList list = new RunList();

    // the venerable, straight-forward technique
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        list.add(() -> {
            /* i'th runnable */
        });
    }

    // a bit of type juggling to concisely add an arbitrary number of Runnables to the list
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(
        () -> { /* runnable 1 */ },
        () -> { /* runnable 2 */ }
    ));

    // or if you're just feeling frisky, these methods too are at your disposal!
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    list.run();
}
```