# Java - multiple Runnables per Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I got a fixed number of threads. I want each thread to run three `Runnable`s, one after another. Here's some  pseudocode to explain:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[4];

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // Set the first tasks.
    threads[i] = new Thread(new FirstRunnable());
    threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    threads[i].join(); // wait until the first tasks are done

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // Set the second task.
    threads[i].setRunnable(new SecondRunnable());
    threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    threads[i].join(); // wait until the second tasks are done

...
```

Using a `ThreadPool` sounds way overkill, especially since I'm headed for performance, performance, performance. What's the best way to implement this in Java?

Comment: that's `{0..3} -> 4` threads and runnables there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two Runnable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661983/combining-two-runnable-objects)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I do not want to start any `SecondRunnable` before not all `FirstRunnable`s are done.

Comment: You may want to look into [`CompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) and [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), probably a [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) along with a [`newFixedThreadPool`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see `new Thread(...).start()`, make use of the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework. In particular, make use of [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: `Executors` is a utility class. The framework or rather the package that bundles all high-level structures for multithreading is the java.util.concurrent package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and a "CombinedRunnable" as shown below. The barrier allows the threads to all wait for each other to finish, before proceeding to the next runnable.

```
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(4);
Runnable r = new CombinedRunnable(barrier, new FirstRunnable(), new SecondRunnable());
Thread[] threads = new Thread[4];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(r);
    threads[i].start();
}
```

The CombinedRunnable class:

```
public class CombinedRunnable implements Runnable{

    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private final Runnable[] runnables;

    public CombinedRunnable(CyclicBarrier barrier, Runnable... runnables){
        this.barrier = barrier;
        this.runnables = runnables;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(Runnable r: runnables){
            r.run();
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good use for a newFixedThreadPool from the [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class.

So your code would look something like:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x ++) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new FirstRunnable()));
}
while (futures.size() > 0) {
   futures.remove(0).get();
}
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x ++) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new SecondRunnable()));
}

while (futures.size() > 0) {
   futures.remove(0).get();
}
```

Of course, you could probably easily refactor the code above to remove code duplication.

Comment: You could use a CompletionService to avoid having to explicitly build and maintain a list of Futures.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to achieve this is by using an `Executor` in conjunction with a `CompletionService`.  This allows you to map many units of work to a fixed size pool of threads and also provides an elegant mechanism for blocking until all work is complete.

Note that your concern about how using a thread pool might impact efficiency is not really an issue: The main overhead is in creating individual threads, which you were doing anyway; the additional object creation overhead in creating a pool will be negligible.

```
// Create fixed thread pool and wrap in a CompletionService to allow for easy access to completed tasks.
// We don't have an explicit result for each Runnable so parameterise the service on Void.
CompletionService<Void> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3));

// Create units of work for submission to completion service.
Runnable[] runnables = ...

// Submit runnables.  Note that we don't care about the result so pass in null.
for (Runnable r : runnables) {
  cs.submit(r, null);
}

// Take each *completed* result in turn, blocking until a completed result becomes available.
for (int i=0; i<runnables.length; ++i) {
  Future<Void> completed = cs.take();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Executor Framework is just for you.
Here's the pseudocode:
1. Create executor service

```
Executors type1Runnables = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Executors type2Runnables = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

etc..
2. Submit tasks to it

```
for(){
type1Runnables.submit(new Runnable1());
type2Runnables.submit(new Runnable2);
}
```

3. Invoke the executors

```
type1Runnables.invokeAll();
type2Runnables.invokeAll();
```

To make it more generic you could perhaps write your own executorservicefactory which accepts the different runnable types.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile: `Executors` cannot be instantiated. Your for-loop is not valid syntax. `ExecutorService.invokeAll(...)` takes parameters. This really is a very lazy and unclear answer, so -1.